# Use of Token with Struts

Tags: java, ajax, struts2, token

I have a problem when i click twice on a link in my application, i have 2 calls done and page is refresh twice, and some error occurs.

So i decide to use token session interceptor to prevent of this errors.

And I'm trying to add struts 2 tokenSession interceptor in my application and i have a problem.

I have add this interceptor with all other interceptor :

```
<interceptor name="tokenSession" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.TokenSessionStoreInterceptor"/>
```

and now, my action look like :

```
<action name="SC002AfficherTestSeuil!*" method="{1}" class="fr.edf.mpv2.castor.actions.surveillance.SC002AfficherTestSeuilAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession"></interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="mpoStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="input">/jsp/fr/edf/mpv2/castor/surveillance/SC002__afficherLesTestsDeSeuil.jsp</result>
        <result name="PAGE_SC002_afficherLesTestsDeSeuil">/jsp/fr/edf/mpv2/castor/surveillance/SC002__afficherLesTestsDeSeuil.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

My page contain a listbox and one button name "show"

when i select item in the listbox, user click on show button and an ajax call is done.

I enter into a method of `public class TokenSessionStoreInterceptor extends TokenInterceptor`

like :

```
 protected String handleInvalidToken(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    ActionContext ac = invocation.getInvocationContext();

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ac.get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) ac.get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_RESPONSE); 
    String tokenName = TokenHelper.getTokenName();
    String token = TokenHelper.getToken(tokenName);

    Map params = ac.getParameters();
    params.remove(tokenName);
    params.remove(TokenHelper.TOKEN_NAME_FIELD);

    if ((tokenName != null) && (token != null)) {
        ActionInvocation savedInvocation = InvocationSessionStore.loadInvocation(tokenName, token);

        if (savedInvocation != null) {
            // set the valuestack to the request scope
            ValueStack stack = savedInvocation.getStack();
            Map context = stack.getContext();
            request.setAttribute(ServletActionContext.STRUTS_VALUESTACK_KEY, stack);

            ActionContext savedContext = savedInvocation.getInvocationContext();
            savedContext.getContextMap().put(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST, request);
            savedContext.getContextMap().put(ServletActionContext.HTTP_RESPONSE, response);
            Result result = savedInvocation.getResult();

            if ((result != null) && (savedInvocation.getProxy().getExecuteResult())) {
                synchronized (context) {
                    result.execute(savedInvocation);
                }
            }

            // turn off execution of this invocations result
            invocation.getProxy().setExecuteResult(false);

            return savedInvocation.getResultCode();
        }
    }

    return INVALID_TOKEN_CODE;
}
```

I don't understand why, but this line `Result result = savedInvocation.getResult();`  always return null, so if you read the struts code; my action is never done and my page is never refresh (remember that is an ajax call, so only a part of the page need to be refresh).

Could someone can give me some help to understand why my result is null? Did i forgot something in the configuration?

thanks a lot

EDIT #1 => add mpoStack

```
<interceptor-stack name="mpoStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="exception" />
            <interceptor-ref name="alias" />
            <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare" />
            <interceptor-ref name="i18n" />
            <interceptor-ref name="chain" />
            <!--<interceptor-ref name="debugging" />-->
            <!--<interceptor-ref name="profiling" />-->
            <!-- Stack d'interceptor sécurité de Marco Polo - Start -->
            <interceptor-ref name="securiteStack" >

            </interceptor-ref>
            <!-- Stack d'interceptor sécurité de Marco Polo - End -->
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload" />
            <interceptor-ref name="checkbox" />
            <interceptor-ref name="staticParams" />
            <interceptor-ref name="params">
                <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <!--<interceptor-ref name="conversionError" />-->
            <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse,execute,retour,annuler</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="jsonValidation"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse,execute,retour,annuler</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
        <interceptor-stack name="mpoStackApplet">
            <interceptor-ref name="alias" />
            <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare" />
            <interceptor-ref name="chain" />
            <interceptor-ref name="securiteStack" />
        </interceptor-stack>
        <!-- QC#3040 PATROL : web.log : Infinite recursion detected -->
        <interceptor-stack name="ErrorStack">
             <interceptor-ref name="exception" />
            <interceptor-ref name="alias" />
            <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare" />
            <interceptor-ref name="i18n" />
            <interceptor-ref name="chain" />
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload" />
            <interceptor-ref name="checkbox" />
            <interceptor-ref name="staticParams" />
            <interceptor-ref name="params">
                <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse,execute,retour,annuler</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="jsonValidation"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse,execute,retour,annuler</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>

    <default-interceptor-ref name="mpoStack" />
```

Comment: Also can you show your mpoStack definition ?

Comment: Try to make a valid token and this code will not be called.

Comment: @AndreaLigios => I have edit my answer to add mpoStack ;)

Comment: @RomanC => Why its a valid token? i don't sure to understand? can you explain more please? thanks

Comment: You have posted a code that handles invalid token. Remove this code or if the token is valid this method should  not be called. The token becomes invalid if it's already used by this interceptor.

Comment: its not my code, its struts2.0.11.1 code for class TokenSessionStoreInterceptor...i dont have to remove anything here, it should normaly work when i do a double click on my webbrowser...but like Andrea suggest, its probably a bug in this version, so i have to ovveride this method and add glue in it! beacuse i can t update to a new struts version. i will give you a feedback when i test this answer.

Comment: hello @RomanC, i understand what you say finally, and if i entered in this method is because :  String sessionToken = (String) session.get(tokenName); return null all the time :( how can i have my token in session to have a valid token the first time? does i forgot something in my configuration? does i need to add explicitly the token into the session? but how? thanks to you

Comment: i find my problem to pass into handleValidToken but i always have a blank page :( i m searching..

Comment: Are you using a default token name or you missing it in the request?

Comment: yes i use the default name, but its an ajax request and at the first click, i entered into handlevalidtoken and token is removed from session, but because of my blank page result, token is not refresh and never put back into the session fot next click. but i don t understand why the first time, when i have a valid token, result is blank, i see that in DefaultActionInvocation : resultConfig = (ResultConfig) results.get(resultCode);, resultCode = none and i don t have results configured with none...so i don t get ResultConfig and action is not execute i guess. but why ResultCode is set to none?

Comment: Your problem cannot be reproduced and off-topic here, please report it to [jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/) on the Apache web site. The answers cannot help if the only solution is to upgrade to the newest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finaly the problem is not the reason why i m having invalidtoken invoken but, like Roman C say in a comment, why i'm not getting a valid token at this point. so i have correct my code to handle valid token and all work fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Appearently it is [Issue WW-3415](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3415) (itself related to [Issue WW-3865](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/) and [Issue WW-3895](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/)).

If this is the case, you could try moving to **2.3.20** that is the first release where it has been fixed.

Alternatively you can try the workaround proposed by OP of the first Issue, changing

```
return savedInvocation.getResultCode();
```

into

```
// Checks if the saved invocation has been executed as of now. 
// If not it gets executed again.
if(savedInvocation.isExecuted()) { 
    return savedInvocation.getResultCode();  
} else { 
    return savedInvocation.invoke(); 
}
```

Comment: ok, i can't test right now but when i have test this i validate or not your answer ;) thanks

Comment: hello, no because problem is not here finaly, thanks for your help because its good to know what you have answered if i m faces to this problem ;)

Comment: Mmok. Feel free to answer your own question if you'll find a solution, to help future visitors. Also consider upvoting this answer if you find it useful